# Get Outlook calendar to Oracle Application Express (APEX)

Tags: oracle, outlook, calendar, oracle-apex

I have created an application in Oracle Application Express (APEX). Now, I need to display the event on calendar. If I use the database in APEX, I just `select EventName, StartDate, EndTime from Table_A` and  link the dates in `Setting` *(Figure 1: Calendar Setting in APEX)*.

[image: Calendar Setting in APEX]

Now, I wish I could get the event details from Outlook Calendar and probably store in oracle table too. 
[image: APEX Application and Outlook Calendar]

May I know the way to sync the record from Outlook?

Comment: The Apex calendar does have built-in support to integrate with Google Calendar, but not Outlook. You'll have to work out how to get data from Outlook into your table yourself.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey ,I was searching about which version of apex have built in support with google calendar.Please provide necessary links.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp I'm interested in the way to sync google calendar with oracle apex too.

Comment: You set **Shared Components -> Component Settings -> Calendar -> Google Calendar API Key** and on the calendar region attributes set **Google Calendar ID**. That's all I know, I haven't tried it myself yet.

Comment: Another thing that may be of help is the calendar attribute **REST Webservice (JSON)** which can be set to a URL for a RESTful Web Service feed of calendar data from an external source to be shown on the calendar.